# Showing data order from Monday-Sunday full week only and hide non-full week data

Tags: sql, sql-server

sorry if I'm shooting newbie questions here.

I want to create a weekly report, but for this weekly report, I want full data from Monday to Sunday

Condition:

- Last 4 weeks only
- Showing full week (Monday - Sunday)
- Hide the result if it's not full week

If i use getdate -14, if I access the data on Wednesday, they will start counting last week from Wednesday 2 weeks ago instead of last Monday. Meanwhile, I want the report to show full week only.

Can anyone share how to do that in SQL?

Here I provide sample data:

```
Column name = DATE -- Column name: TOTAL_PERSON
    - Fri, 1 Jun 2018 -- 10
    - Sat, 2 Jun 2018 -- 4
    - Sun, 3 Jun 2018 -- 12
    - Mon, 4 Jun 2018 -- 15
    - Tue, 5 Jun 2018 -- 10
    - Wed, 6 Jun 2018 -- 3
    - Thu, 7 Jun 2018 -- 1
    - Fri, 8 Jun 2018 -- 13
    - Sat, 9 Jun 2018 -- 9
    - Sun, 10 Jun 2018 -- 23
    - Mon, 11 Jun 2018 -- 5
    - Tue, 12 Jun 2018 -- 3
    - Wed, 13 Jun 2018 -- 1
    - Thu, 14 Jun 2018 -- (TODAY)
```

In this case, if I am accessing on Thu 6 Jun 2018 I want to get **TOTAL PERSON** data from Mon, 4 Jun 2018 to Sun, 10 Jun 2018 only and not showing data from the rest since the week is not full.

Can anyone help me how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. What are you *really* using?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I should tag 'SQL' only

Comment: Please specify database engine you're using in tags

Comment: The <sql> tag is for ANSI SQL. Neither SQL Server nor MySQL is ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time, so you'd better add the tag for the dbms you're actually using.

Comment: No, you need to tag your RDBMS. Different DBMS use different "flavours" of SQL. For example SQL Server uses T-SQL, Oracle PL-SQL (If I recall correctly), MySQL's is also different again.

Comment: “Last 4 weeks only”, does that mean that the input date is only within the last 4 weeks and that you want reports for the full week of that date and any full weeks between the input date and today?

Comment: The reference to "getdate" suggests that the database is SQL Server.

Comment: hi all, yes it's SQL Server!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
where datediff(week, date, getdate()) <= 2
```

This counts the number of week boundaries between two dates, so it returns an entire week.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, you can use such a select:

```
SELECT * FROM `myDB` WHERE `Date` 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW()-INTERVAL DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%w') DAY, INTERVAL 28 DAY) 
AND NOW()- INTERVAL DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%w') DAY
```

This uses the capability to transform the current day of this week into a number and substract this to get the last Sunday. from there, we select an intervall of 28 days.

(Only testet with 14 days and a very limited test-dataset, but should work)